# "Exceptional" rule for Tuckey URL Rewrite Filter

Tags: regex, redirect, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Guys! I'm using Tuckey URL Rewrite Filter and I want all those requests which were **not** started with "/specialUrl/" being now prefixed with "/prefixUrl/". For example:

- "/specialUrl/xxx" stands as it is ("/specialUrl/xxx"), but
- "/otherUrl/xxx" transforms to "/prefixUrl/otherUrl/xxx";
- "/xxx" also transforms to "/prefixUrl/xxx".

How should I describe such a rule(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
<rule match-type="regex">
  <condition name="request-uri" operator="notequal">^/specialUrl/.*$</condition>
  <from>^/(.*)$</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect">/specialUrl/$1</to>
</rule>
```